# Can I add additional configuration to a paragraph type?

Tags: paragraphs, 9

Is it possible to add some field directly in the paragraph config ? For example, I'd like to add another image under to **paragraph icon**

The field should not be editable by the user, that why it's not a "class paragraph field"

[image]

Comment: It's called third party settings.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example for this situation please ?

Comment: You can also create a normal field and then simply hide it in the form mode to make it un-editable by users.